# Java-Write in file

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane, randomaccessfile

I want get name, last name and a spacial code from user, and save in one array, after that write to a file. My code doesn't have compiler error but it doesn't work.

```
public class WriteFile {

public static void main(String[] args){

    try {

        String array[][] = new String[100][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile("D://employee.txt","rw");
            String inputName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert First Name");
            array[i][0]=inputName;
            String inputLName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert Last Name");
            array[i][1]=inputLName;
            String inputMeliiC=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert Melii Code");
            array[i][2]=inputMeliiC;

            raf.writeUTF(array[i][0]);
            raf.writeUTF(array[i][1]) ;
            raf.writeUTF(array[i][1]);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


}
```

Comment: You should close the file raf.close()

Comment: Also, what doesn't work ?

Comment: You seem to be writing `array[i][1]` twice.

Comment: create & close your file after loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well you can for this modified code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    try {

        String array[][] = new String[2][3];
        raf=new RandomAccessFile("D:\\employee.txt","rw");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String inputName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert First Name");
            array[i][0]=inputName;
            String inputLName=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert Last Name");
            array[i][1]=inputLName;
            String inputMeliiC=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Insert Melii Code");
            array[i][2]=inputMeliiC;

            raf.writeChars(array[i][0]);
            raf.writeChar(':');
            raf.writeChars(array[i][1]) ;
            raf.writeChar(':');
            raf.writeChars(array[i][2]);
            raf.writeChars("\n");

        }
        raf.seek(0);

        String str = raf.readLine();
        while(str != null ){
            System.out.println(str);
            String arr[] = str.split(":");
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
            str = raf.readLine();
        }

        raf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                try {
                    raf.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Ideone.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    raf.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Ideone.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: You should .close() in a finally block; otherwise the file won't be closed if a write fails for some reason.

Comment: Yes it should be. I have just give example user can modify accordingly.

Comment: thanks alot. It writes on file, but how can I split words?          f a r i h e i d a r i 1 2 1 0 0 3 4 0

Comment: You can write split symbol like raf.writeChars(":"); and then read entire line at once and using string split function which will return a string array then use as you want.

Comment: I check this code. It's so good but If I want write any array ( any person) in separate line, what can I do?

Comment: well you can include one more line after writing all data for i cycle like this :raf.writeChars("\n"); i have also edited my original code.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing many things wrong.

First of all, why do you use an array at all here? It is unwarranted. Collect in a `List`!

Second: `.writeUTF()` will not write text.

Third: why write as you ask for input? Write all at once.

Fourth: you don't close your resource at all.

Ask for input first, then attempt to write to the file. And don't use `File`, it's obsolete. Use this (supposes Java 7+):

```
final Path dst = Paths.get("d:\\employee.txt");

// Change open options if necessary
try (
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
) {
    // write your data
}
```

Or even better yet, use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). Provided you have collected all of your employee data in a `List` as I suggest, and not an array, this is as easy as:

```
Files.write(thePath, myList, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, yourOpenOptionsHere);
```

Comment: that is assuming he is using java 7, if not he can't use Paths

Comment: @MihaiC hey, this is 2014 :p

Comment: I agree, but still, who knows what his requirement is :) it's better to at least let him know what version he needs to use, and/or an alternative if he can't use it

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- You defined array as `new String[100][2]` and using it till the index `array[i][2]=inputMeliiC;` As array starts from 0, you should define your array as new String[100][3]. Are you doing further processing on your array?
- You are not writing the inputMeliiC, instead you are duplicating the inputLName bu doing `raf.writeUTF(array[i][1]);` twice. You should do `raf.writeUTF(array[i][2]);`
- Most importantly why you r write is not working is, you need to flush out the buffer. So you should do `raf.close();` once you are done. Make sure UTF wont write in simple text as you are entering and you are opening file in both read write mode.

Comment: I want write in file and after that search on them. For example fine spacial melliCode and read his name and last name

Comment: Why file? Why not just within an array or some collections?

Comment: I take a Java class and it is my home work :) . I am very novice and learner. I don't know other ways

Comment: Ok i see you are done and accepted the answer. So i assume you completed your homework :)